# Cannot Read $_SESSION data for redirection

Tags: php, session

I want to read `$_SESSION` data on a page so that if it does not match with the data on *that* page, the page redirects to another page. However, the page gets redirected **EVERY** time, no matter what the `$_SESSION` data is. I tried to debug with `var_dump($_SESSION)`, but everything came out to be right. Please Help!

My **Page1.php**:

```
<?php
 $me=strtoupper($_POST[username]);
 $_SESSION["user"]=$me; // var_dump shows this value is "ADAM"
?>
```

My **Page2.php**:

```
<?php
 $me="ADAM";
 if($_SESSION["user"]!=$me){
  header("location: ../index.php");
  die;
 }
?>
```

Comment: start session : `session_start()` add this line at top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was missing out on `session_start()` at the beginning of my scripts. Here are my codes now:

My `Page1.php`:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $me=strtoupper($_POST[username]);
   $_SESSION["user"]=$me; // var_dump shows this value is "ADAM"
?>
```

My `Page2.php`:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $me="ADAM";
   if($_SESSION["user"]!=$me){
      header("location: ../index.php");
      die;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see that you're using `session_start()` anywhere. You need to use that on each and every page that you want to use the `$_SESSION` global.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `session_start();` on all pages that are going to use `$_SESSION` superglobal variable.

Answer (score -1):

every file begin add code " session_start(); "

try  again!!